# system crash reason

Tags: debugging

One of our server recently get frequently crash....I am pasting some of the syslog here, anyone familar with system would give me a hint what caused this? Much appreciated.

I am using Ubuntu 12.10.

```
Sep 26 12:45:22 epgg2 kernel: [  183.799965] Pid: 1718, comm: subtleKnife Not tainted 3.5.0-17-generic #28-Ubuntu Dell Inc. PowerEdge M710HD/037M3H
Sep 26 12:45:22 epgg2 kernel: [  183.800593] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffffa029ba73>]  [<ffffffffa029ba73>] nfs_file_set_open_context+0x23/0x80 [nfs]
Sep 26 12:45:22 epgg2 kernel: [  183.801163] RSP: 0018:ffff882414253b88  EFLAGS: 00010286
Sep 26 12:45:22 epgg2 kernel: [  183.801467] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff882415c22100 RCX: 0000000000000046
Sep 26 12:45:22 epgg2 kernel: [  183.801922] RDX: 0000000000000046 RSI: ffff882415c22100 RDI: ffff882417960500
Sep 26 12:45:22 epgg2 kernel: [  183.802414] RBP: ffff882414253ba8 R08: 0000000000000003 R09: 0000000000000003
Sep 26 12:45:22 epgg2 kernel: [  183.802923] R10: 0000000014930401 R11: ffffffffa02af354 R12: ffff882415903e00
Sep 26 12:45:22 epgg2 kernel: [  183.803341] R13: ffff882415c22100 R14: ffff8824147b05d8 R15: ffff882415863680
Sep 26 12:45:22 epgg2 kernel: [  183.803751] FS:  00007f6a486fb700(0000) GS:ffff88247fc00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Sep 26 12:45:22 epgg2 kernel: [  183.804217] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 000000008005003b
Sep 26 12:45:22 epgg2 kernel: [  183.813112] CR2: 0000000000000030 CR3: 0000002417dbb000 CR4: 00000000000007f0
Sep 26 12:45:22 epgg2 kernel: [  183.822364] DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
Sep 26 12:45:22 epgg2 kernel: [  183.831519] DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000ffff0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
Sep 26 12:45:22 epgg2 kernel: [  183.840683] Process subtleKnife (pid: 1718, threadinfo ffff882414252000, task ffff8824150e9700)
Sep 26 12:45:22 epgg2 kernel: [  183.858177] Stack:
Sep 26 12:45:22 epgg2 kernel: [  183.866686]  ffff882417960500 0000000000000000 ffff882415903e00 ffff882415c22100
Sep 26 12:45:22 epgg2 kernel: [  183.884425]  ffff882414253c58 ffffffffa0299059 0000000014253bd8 ffff8824158d72b0
Sep 26 12:45:22 epgg2 kernel: [  183.902915]  0000800017960510 ffff8824158d72b0 0001000000008000 ffff88241641dc00
Sep 26 12:45:22 epgg2 kernel: [  183.921834] Call Trace:
Sep 26 12:45:22 epgg2 kernel: [  183.930943]  [<ffffffffa0299059>] nfs4_file_open+0x169/0x1b0 [nfs]
Sep 26 12:45:22 epgg2 kernel: [  183.940062]  [<ffffffff8118010f>] __dentry_open+0x21f/0x330
Sep 26 12:45:22 epgg2 kernel: [  183.948970]  [<ffffffffa0298ef0>] ? nfs_setlease+0x10/0x10 [nfs]
Sep 26 12:45:22 epgg2 kernel: [  183.958192]  [<ffffffff8118025a>] vfs_open+0x3a/0x40
Sep 26 12:45:22 epgg2 kernel: [  183.966984]  [<ffffffff81181208>] nameidata_to_filp+0x58/0xb0
Sep 26 12:45:22 epgg2 kernel: [  183.975650]  [<ffffffff8118fb3f>] do_last+0x49f/0xa10
Sep 26 12:45:22 epgg2 kernel: [  183.984227]  [<ffffffff81191399>] path_openat+0xd9/0x430
Sep 26 12:45:22 epgg2 kernel: [  183.992336]  [<ffffffff810561ec>] ? release_task+0x2cc/0x480
Sep 26 12:45:22 epgg2 kernel: [  184.000385]  [<ffffffff81191811>] do_filp_open+0x41/0xa0
Sep 26 12:45:22 epgg2 kernel: [  184.008385]  [<ffffffff8119e906>] ? alloc_fd+0xc6/0x110
Sep 26 12:45:22 epgg2 kernel: [  184.016628]  [<ffffffff81181355>] do_sys_open+0xf5/0x230
Sep 26 12:45:22 epgg2 kernel: [  184.024512]  [<ffffffff811814b1>] sys_open+0x21/0x30Sep 26 12:45:22 epgg2 kernel: [  184.032264]  [<ffffffff81689d29>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
Sep 26 12:45:22 epgg2 kernel: [  184.040002] Code: 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 55 48 89 e5 48 83 ec 20 48 89 5d e8 4c 89 65 f0 4c 89 6d f8 66 66 66 66 90 48 8b 47 18 48
 85 f6 48 89 f3 <4c> 8b 68 30 74 03 f0 ff 06 4d 8d a5 88 00 00 00 48 89 9f a0 00 
Sep 26 12:45:22 epgg2 kernel: [  184.064228] RIP  [<ffffffffa029ba73>] nfs_file_set_open_context+0x23/0x80 [nfs]
Sep 26 12:45:22 epgg2 kernel: [  184.080078]  RSP <ffff882414253b88>
Sep 26 12:45:22 epgg2 kernel: [  184.088187] CR2: 0000000000000030
Sep 26 12:45:22 epgg2 kernel: [  184.096113] ---[ end trace 4a4d24758d2ccf4f ]---
Sep 26 12:45:22 epgg2 kernel: [  184.095989] BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at 0000000f00010a0e
Sep 26 12:45:22 epgg2 kernel: [  184.120329] IP: [<ffffffff8103f989>] __ticket_spin_lock+0x9/0x30
Sep 26 12:45:22 epgg2 kernel: [  184.128303] PGD 2415580067 PUD 0 
Sep 26 12:45:22 epgg2 kernel: [  184.136792] Oops: 0002 [#2] SMP 
Sep 26 12:45:22 epgg2 kernel: [  184.144177] CPU 2 
Sep 26 12:45:22 epgg2 kernel: [  184.144293] Modules linked in: vesafb nfsd nfs lockd fscache auth_rpcgss nfs_acl sunrpc dcdbas gpio_ich coretemp kvm ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel cryptd aes_x86_64 microcode joydev lpc_ich i7core_edac edac_core mac_hid wmi acpi_power_meter lp parport hid_generic usbhid hid bnx2x libcrc32c mpt2sas mdio scsi_transport_sas bnx2 raid_class
```

Comment: Try to disable nfs for the time being to troubleshoot further. After all it's crashing. As you can see in the logs, the hint is NFS.

Comment: Yes, good point....while I need NFS as I am mounting the storage for our website....

Answer (score 1):

It is probably a bug in the BIOS, kernel or the nsf module. You should update your BIOS firmaware if a newer version is available, upgrade the kernel, preferably to latest version and see if it still happens. If it does report a bug using [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) guide.